# Como acessar propriedades de um objeto dentro de outro objeto no ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, react

Estou consumindo via axios o seguinte JSON: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5

Quando tento acessar pessoa.name.title recebo o seguinte erro:

> [image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined]

Só consigo acessar a propriedade title quando digito dessa forma `{pessoa.name && pessoa.name.title`,

Alguém sabe me explicar porquê?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import api from "../../services/api"

class CardPeople extends Component {
    constructor(props){  
        super(props)  
        this.state = { 
            pessoas: [
                {    
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const people_api = await api.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5");           
        this.setState({
            pessoas: people_api.data.results
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
             {this.state.pessoas.map((pessoa, index) =>
            <Col key={pessoa.gender}>                               
                <p> {pessoa.name && pessoa.name.title}</p><br></br>                 
            </Col>
            )}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verificando seu código acabei descobrindo que foi iniciado o `array` de `pessoas` com um objeto vazio, ***observe***:

```
this.state = { 
    pessoas: [
        { // <-- aqui o problema
        } // <-- aqui o problema
    ]
}
```

mas, no caso como não tem itens no `array` (os itens que vão ser carregados após o componente estar totalmente carregado), só precisa informar para o `script` que é um `array` sem item (com tamanho 0), ***exemplo***:

```
this.state = { 
    pessoas: [] //correto
}
```

ou seja, como foi iniciado o `array` com um objeto sem chaves e valores, causa no inicio do carregamento desse *componente* a exceção como demonstrada na sua pergunta por falta de informação que somente está disponível a partir da requisição.

---

Eu acabei simulando um exemplo e no meu caso funcionou perfeitamente, **exemplo**:

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
    this.getResults =
      this.getResults.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
     this.getResults();
  }
  
  getResults() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
        this.setState({results: r.results});
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.results.map((p,i) => <li key={i}>{p.name.title}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

O exemplo acima foi realmente para demonstrar o funcionamento, só difere que foi utilizado um API própria do [javacript](/questions/tagged/javacript) para buscar informações nessa `url` mas, o problema na verdade é como foi explicado só fazer alteração removendo o objeto vazio do `array` que o seu código vai funcionar.

Comment: Foi justamente isso, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.